# How to pass variable from function to methods inside utility class in React? ‍♂️

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a react project. I was trying to pass variable "locationProps" from function to the method in my class. But I don't know how to send the variable and how to access the variable in the method.

```
function Daily({ locationProps = 2, root }) {
  const context = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const localization = useCallback(() => {
    if (root && cookies.get("location") !== undefined) {
      return cookies.get("location");
    }
    return locationProps;
  }, [locationProps, root]);
```

```
class dayData {
  constructor() {
    this.updateData();
  }

  getSpeadsheetUrl() {
    return config.prData[locationProps];
  }
```

Comment: Can you share where are you rendering `dayData`?

Comment: What is the relationShip between dayData and Daily. Seems like dayData isn't a component but a class utility

Comment: yes class utility

Comment: Do it as a component and send variable like <DayData locationProps ={locationProps} />